# Generating ZipFile with Django from already defined classes

Tags: python, django

I have 2 defined classes in my views that generate CSV files. I want to give the option of downloading both files at once in a zip file or each individually. 
I've created this class in my views to generate my ZIP

```
class ExportInitiativeAssessmentsView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
 model = AssessmentSubmission
 queryset = AssessmentSubmission.objects.filter(assessment__slug__in= . 
 ['init_exec', 'init_registration'])
 def get_queryset(self):
    if self.request.user.is_superuser:
        queryset = self.queryset
    else:
        queryset =
```

self.queryset.filter(registration__partner_organization=self.request.user.partner)
        return queryset
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

```
    headers = {
        'registration__youth__first_name': 'First Name',
        'registration__youth__father_name': "Fathers's Name",

    }
    qs = self.get_queryset()..values(
        'registration__youth__first_name',
        'registration__youth__father_name',    
    )

    filename = 'Initiative-Export'
    return render_to_csv_response(qs, filename,  field_header_map=headers)


class ExportPBI(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    file1 = ExportInitiativeAssessmentsView.as_view()  # Class defined above and returned a csv file
    file2 = ExportRegistryAssessmentsView().as_view()  # Class defined above and returned a csv file
    current_files = [file1, file2,]
    zipped_file = StringIO.StringIO()

    with zipfile.ZipFile(zipped_file, 'w') as zip:
        for file in current_files:
            zip.write('Initiative-Export.csv')
    zipped_file.close()
```

Comment: I would first try to make this work with one file. Can you show what the ExportInitiativeAssessmentsView does?

Comment: It works for individual CSV files. My problem is with adding the individual files to the zip file.